# Inserting ContentDistribution

Tags: apex, query, content

I have a `ContentVersion` (zip file) and I am trying to insert a `ContentDistribution` in Apex to get the `DistributionPublicUrl` field related to my file. I get this error:

> Line: 3, Column: 1
>   System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Related Record ID: id value of incorrect type: 06946000000uPLHAA2: [RelatedRecordId]

My code :

```
ContentDistribution test = new ContentDistribution();
test.RelatedRecordId = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Title='ZipTest'].ContentDocumentId;
insert test;
```

Is `RelatedRecordId` the appropriate field to set? Or is it a problem with `ContentDocumentId`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for [`ContentDisbribution`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdistribution.htm?search_text=contentdistribution), it seems like you should be setting the `ContentVersionId` field.

The `RelatedRecordId` field is polymorphic, but doesn't appear to be relatable to `ContentVersion`:

```
Set<SObjectType> referenceTo = new Set<SObjectType>(
    ContentDistribution.RelatedRecordId.getDescribe().getReferenceTo()
);
system.assert(!referenceTo.contains(ContentVersion.sObjectType));
```

Note the documentation's description of this field:

> ID of the record, such as an Account, Campaign, or Case, that the shared document is related to.

Comment: Thank you ! Creating a ContentDistribution by setting ContentVersionId and a name works perfectly !